# CSS linked to page based on browser cache?

Tags: html, css, browser-cache

It seems to me that the link tags to refer CSS files on a web page are conditionally included if they are already cached by the browser. Is this possible? If yes, how can we get around the problem.

I go directly to  `www.xyz.com/advanced` and do a view-source, there are no link tags to CSS

But if I go to `www.xyz.com/home` first (which has the CSS link tags) and then go to `www.xyz.com/advanced`, the source has the required link tags for the CSS files like below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/gold/css/dpstyles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="local/css/styles.css" />
```

Comment: Which browser does this occur in? It seems very unlikely that would be the case, if that is happening as described it's more likely a site specific thing.

Comment: @DBS: It occurs in IE, Mozilla and Chrome too. Any ideas to get around and force the site to generate those link tags all the time?

Comment: The server has no idea what's cached in your browser, but I guess it could make a guess using cookies/session data. However this seems like very weird functionality for the site to have, can you link to the site where this happens (if it's publicly available) so we can see it for ourselves?